# Getting started with Forex Trading

Tags: fx

I have $2000 that I can risk losing.

I'd like to get started with Forex Trading.

Is there some place where I can open an account, get free API access, and write basic programs to play with the data? [I'd prefer a Java interface as I'd like to use Clojure.]

Thanks!

Comment: This site is intended for professional quants. See the [FAQ](http://quant.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: You can try JForex API.

Answer (score 2):

www.interactivebrokers.com

They have a Java API, they have a paper trading account once you funded your account. But I guess this question will not make it too long on this forum as this forum is more quant focused. I recommend you go to www.elitetrader.com and ask such questions there.